# Flask import error: No module named app. While creating the database with Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, importerror, python-import

Hi I am very new to flask and I am trying to set up a database using sqlite with my app. I have the file structure like this

```
app
|--Static(folder)
|--Templates(folder)
|--__init__.py (empty python file)
|--models.py(containes table classes)
|--app.py (application module)
```

inside my app.py file I have the following code

```
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash 
from datetime import datetime
from logging import DEBUG


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'database.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

So when I try to run the command

```
from app.app import db
```

in the python shell, I get the error saying that "no module named app".
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: from what directory are you running the python shell ?

Comment: I am running it inside the app directory

Comment: so you have an extra app in your command, or launch python  from upper dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to run

```
from app.app import db
```

This command would import a module from a "app" class called "db" in the file "app", which you don't have and I don't imagine you're trying to do.

You should just be executing your app from the terminal via

```
python app.py
```

This will just execute the code that is in the app.py file.

You can find more about this by following the flask tutorial [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/setup/)